# AWS Billing for Data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We are using **AWS** and i am using s3 **service** only. 
Do i need to pay for Data transfer service ?

[image: Screen shot of my Bill]

How to stop Data transfer service ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand each section you will see more detail. All outbound data transfer from any amazon service incurs a bandwidth cost. Inbound data is free in most cases. Pricing also varies by region.

The only way you can stop the data transfer cost is to not download any data from S3.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.. As we need to download data from S3 for using on my website.. We are storing images to s3 and showing to website.